# Who provides syscalls in qemu-riscv?

Tags: qemu, riscv

I started learn riscv. I got qemu-riscv, riscv-gcc and compiled next hello world asm program:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

    li a0, 0                    # stdout
1:  auipc a1, %pcrel_hi(msg)    # load msg(hi)
    addi a1, a1, %pcrel_lo(1b)  # load msg(lo)
    li a2, 12                   # length
    li a3, 0
    li a7, 64                   # _NR_sys_write
    ecall                       # system call

    li a0, 0
    li a1, 0
    li a2, 0
    li a3, 0
    li a7, 93                   # _NR_sys_exit
    ecall                       # system call

loop:
    j loop

.section .rodata
msg:
    .string "Hello World\n"
```

Here are using syscalls (_NR_sys_write, _NR_sys_exit) and that's confusing me - I think I run "bare metal" program, but why a syscalls are being used implicitly? Why this syscalls is proxied by qemu and what will happens if I run this code on fpga riscv where is no imlemented syscalls?

ps: It's really hard to find any risc-v programming tutorial or processor bare-metal configuration for me. There is some poorly commented code of ported OSs (FreeRTOS, Linux and FreeBSD) but there is no any explanation. Could you also help me with this info?

Comment: Can you give the exact name of the toolchain you used?

Comment: @Guillaume riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc

Comment: Ah, I see. I have used qemu riscv64-linux-user instead of riscv64-softmmu (qemu-system-riscv64). That is the reason why qemu proxies syscalls to linux. Thanks for hint.

Comment: I was my guess. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

There are three families of targets in QEMU:

- User-mode emulation, where QEMU provides an AEE (Application Execution Environment).  In this mode, QEMU itself acts as the supervisor -- in other words, when QEMU sees an `ecall` it will decode the syscall number/arguments, perform the system call, and then return to emulating instructions.  QEMU's user-mode emulation is thus tied to a specific supervisor's ABI, with the only instance I've seen in RISC-V land being Linux.
- Soft MMU, where QEMU provides an MEE (Machine Execution Environment).  In this mode the entire software stack is run as if it was running on a full RISC-V system with QEMU providing emulated devices -- in other words, when QEMU sees an `ecall` it will start emulating code at the trap vector.  Here QEMU doesn't need to know anything about the supervisor as the exact supervisor code is running.
- Hardware virtualization, where QEMU provides a HEE (Hypervisor Execution Environment) while relying on hardware emulation to provide better performance.  We don't have this working on RISC-V yet (as of October 2018), but there are specifications in progress along with early implementation work.

If you see `ecall` instructions in userspace just magicly working, then you're probably running in user-mode emulation.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Small addendum on my ps: I found bare-metal examples which runs in qemu and existed hw configurations https://github.com/michaeljclark/riscv-probe

Comment: If you're running system-mode QEMU then you should be able to run any HiFive1 example on the "sifive_e" board.